# Call several dependant functions before render

Tags: reactjs

I need to fetch data before the render function is called. I do this in `componentDidMount`. In this I call a function which returns data which is used in another function call. How can I wait for this data?

```
state = {
  myData: []
};

componentDidMount() {
var result = [];

getAllData().then((valuesReturnedByAPI) => {
  valuesReturnedByAPI.forEach(element => {
    getSpecificData(element.key).then((status) => {
      result.push({
        name: element.name,
        status: status
      });                    
    });
  });            
}).then(() => {
  // I would like to set the state only once when all data has been pushed into result
  this.setState({            
    myData: result
  });        
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Promise.all` to wait for all inner requests to complete.

```
componentDidMount() {
getAllData().then((valuesReturnedByAPI) => {
  return Promise.all(valuesReturnedByAPI.map(element => {
    return getSpecificData(element.key).then((status) => {
      return {
        name: element.name,
        status
      };                    
    });
  }));            
}).then((myData) => {
  // I would like to set the state only once when all data has been pushed into result
  this.setState({            
    myData
  });        
});
}
```

Formatted version w/ implicit return

```
componentDidMount() {
    getAllData()
      .then(valuesReturnedByAPI =>
        Promise.all(
          valuesReturnedByAPI.map(element =>
            getSpecificData(element.key).then(status => ({
              name: element.name,
              status
            }))
          )
        )
      )
      .then(myData => this.setState({ myData }));
  }
```

Comment: @T3rm1 Glad I could help.